# How to import webflow into Angular > 9

Tags: angular, webflow

I tried to import a webflow generated single page into my angular app, which is going to be lazy loaded once visited in a subpage.

I've created a sub page, imported the html part of webflow in `example-webflow.component.html` and binded the css directly into the `example-webflow.component.scss`. *I've tried to import the js in `angular.json` but didn't seems to work.*

Does somebody already did such import?

*I saw it was working with angular <= 6 with this library [freeformjs](https://www.freeformjs.org/) but doesn't seems to work anymore*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't found any way of doing it so I've decided to :

1. Import the `webflow` export into my angular `assets` folder
2. Used the iframe to load the webflow component with `src='/assets/webflow/index.html'`

Answer (score 1):

*I didn't test this solution*
This is an answer to @RamiAssi, since his solution is going in the right direction, but wont make this usable in every case & also, the question was about lazy loading & not loading when loading my main application

If you would like to load scripts & not do as the accepted answer does, I would recommend doing as follow.

Load this in the `ngOnInit()`you wants, the `isScriptLoaded` will make sure you do not load multiple time the same script

Then, await from the script to being loaded before you load the webflow html

```js
export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {
 loading = true

 ngOnInit(): void {
   if(this.loadScript('assets/theme/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js') && this.loadScript('assets/theme/js/workflow.js')) 
    this.loading = false
  }
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!loading"> 
  <!-- My webflow stuff -->
</ng-container>
```

```js
/**
 *
 * @param target url to be loaded
 * @returns true when loaded
 */
export const loadScript = (target: string): boolean => {
  if (!isScriptLoaded(target)) {
    const tag = document.createElement('script')
    tag.src = target
    document.body.appendChild(tag)
    return true
  }

  return true
}

export const isScriptLoaded = (target: string): boolean => {
  return document.querySelector('script[src="' + target + '"]') ? true : false
}
```

#### Point of optimization

You could make a method that load multiple scripts

Answer (score 0):

I could manage to make the webflow work in an Angular project by adding the webflow and jquery js files dynamically to the document head. After the app component view is initialized.

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

const dynamicScripts = [
  'assets/theme/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js',
  'assets/theme/js/webflow.js',
  ];

@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.loadScript();
  }

  public loadScript() {
    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
      const node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.async = false;
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. But I see some negatives impact on the way you did it. 
1. You're loading this directly in the app.component, why not directly in the angular.json file ? 2. This will then broke the lazy loading experience, which will make the first initial load being slower. 3. How are you sure those scripts will be loaded before your workflow html file ?

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer to load the webflow script in ngAfterViewInit. This will have impact on performance, I guess. Honestly, this the best solution I could reach to integrate webflow with Angular.

Comment: I've added a new respond, would this help you ? (Since you aren't really giving a response to the question, but may be in the right direction